# How to marge third party select box into one?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I have third party search gadget on my WordPress website, I want to marge Region & Location dropdown into one.

Region Tab Code as below:

```
<div class="regionFilter">
   <span class="label"><label>Region</label></span>
   <span class="input">
      <select>
         <option value="">--- All ---</option>
         <option value="Bali">Bali</option>
         <option value="Thailand">Thailand</option>
      </select>
   </span>
</div>
```

Location Tab Code as below:

```
<div class="locationsFilter">
   <span class="label"><label>Location</label></span>
   <span class="input">
      <select>
         <option value="">--- All ---</option>
         <option value="Patong">Patong</option>
         <option value="Pattaya">Pattaya</option>
         <option value="Seminyak">Seminyak</option>
         <option value="Ubud">Ubud</option>
         <option value="Uluwatu">Uluwatu</option>
      </select>
   </span>
</div>
```

After Merging Region data into location filter I need final result something like below code. So, it'll be a grouping region as location wise.

```
<div class="locationsFilter">
   <span class="label"><label>Location</label></span>
   <span class="input">
      <select>
         <option value="">--- All ---</option>
         <option value="Bali">--- Bali ---</option>
         <option value="Seminyak">Seminyak</option>
         <option value="Ubud">Ubud</option>
         <option value="Uluwatu">Uluwatu</option>
         <option value="Thailand">--- Thailand ---</option>
         <option value="Patong">Patong</option>
         <option value="Pattaya">Pattaya</option>
      </select>
   </span>
</div>
```

I have no access on that third party code everything what I have to do is using wordpress, php, javascript and jquery

Comment: A hack that you should do is when everything loads, read the options on the first one, delete the first one, than add the options to the second one.. if its too "obvious" that you are doing that in the GUI, you can add some kind of "loading" short thing on top

Comment: @DenkoMancheski I am not good in javascript if you know how to perform this jQuery.merge() function with third party select option then it'll helpful.